# Unknown SMTP host: outlook.office365.com;

Tags: java, email, outlook

I have written code in java to send mail. The issue I am facing is UnknownHostException. I am using SMTP Host as outlook.office.com as the email account from where i want to send the mail is corporate and accessed using outlook. Here is the code.

```
Properties props=new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host","outlook.office365.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
        Session session=Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                return new PasswordAuthentication(sender, password);
            }
        });
```

The session object is not null as I have put a check on that. If session is getting created then what is the reason I am facing this exception?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you behind a corporate firewall? It may not allow direct connections to port 587.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host","outlook.office365.com");
```

to

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.office365.com");
```

or

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "m.outlook.com");
```

for more info, visit [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c) and [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn554323(v=exchg.150).aspx#HowtoconfigSMTPCS) site.

Comment: @honeypreet did you set propert userid and password?

Comment: also try `props.put("mail.smtp.host", "m.outlook.com")`